# Looking for way to download all the free software I need to setup my PC all at once . .

Tags: windows, installation, download

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [One-stop-shop installer for free Windows software?](https://superuser.com/questions/69751/one-stop-shop-installer-for-free-windows-software)

I am in the middle of reinstalling Windows 7, and I would like to install all the software in as few steps as possible.

I saw a web site recently that listed a lot of different Freeware and Opensource appliations.  There was a checkmark next to each one so you could select the ones you want, and then they would all download in a single package to install at one time.  The idea was for when you were setting up after a fresh install.

It was for Windows and they were adding 64-bit applications.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Ninite](http://ninite.com/)

Comment: The simplicity of this answer is just remarkable.

Answer (score 3):

There's also [allmyapps.com](http://www.allmyapps.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Use **[ZeuAPP](http://zeuapp.en.malavida.com/)**.

> Pick software that you want, start
> download and install it. One click
> download the application you want to
> install, ZeuAPP in its list contains
> 160 applications. All applications are
> freeware or open source, and you are
> free to download them.
>
> ZeuAPP has 14+1
> categories: Archivers, Audio, Video,
> Chat-IM, Internet, CD Burners,
> P2P-File sharing, (Games),
> Programming, Graphic, Text editors,
> Office, Security, Utilities, Runitmes
> +My Software.
>
> License: GPLv3

[image]

Comment: Cheers @Mehper. I used a combination of Ninte & AllMyApps. Ninite was easy - AllMyApps is great in theory but the versions it has are not the latest. Chocolatey looks promising.